# Learning assembly - all commented, need to generate pseudocode

Tags: c, assembly

I'm getting more proficient at reading assembly, but now I'm at a phase where I need to bridge my understanding with actually constructing C pseudocode. I've commented out this entire passage as part of an assignment and added what I think is going on below. **I've pretty much done the work here. I just need some help verifying my understanding and ensuring that my interpretation is correct.**

```
804990f:       ba 94 ae 04 08          mov    $0x804ae94,%edx // this, on gdb is actually %d %d %d
8049914:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax // function argument - parameter1 - being loaded into the eax to be considered
8049917:       8d 4d e0                lea    -0x20(%ebp),%ecx // local pointer being loaded into the ecx register
804991a:       89 4c 24 10             mov    %ecx,0x10(%esp) // this local pointer is now being added to the stack
804991e:       8d 4d e4                lea    -0x1c(%ebp),%ecx  // local pointer being loaded into the ecx register
8049921:       89 4c 24 0c             mov    %ecx,0xc(%esp) // this local pointer is now being added to the stack
8049925:       8d 4d e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%ecx // local pointer being loaded into the ecx register
8049928:       89 4c 24 08             mov    %ecx,0x8(%esp) // this local pointer is now being added to the stack
804992c:       89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp) // the three "d d d" is now also being moved to another area at the top of the stack
8049930:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp) // the value of parameter one is now being treated as a pointer because address is being loaded in
8049933:       e8 38 f3 ff ff          call   8048c70 <sscanf@plt> // the scan function is now being called, to take in three values we passed into the array
8049938:       83 f8 03                cmp    $0x3,%eax // it is comparing the parameter value which is now in the array(array[0]) to the constant 3
804993b:       74 05                   je     8049942 <level_3+0x39> // if the parameter is == to 3, it jumps. so it should be like if (greater/less than)
804993d:       e8 10 fa ff ff          call   8049352 <call_function> // if it is not meeting these conditions, call this function



8049942:       c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp) // move the constant 0 into a local variable x
8049949:       8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax // move array[2] into the register
804994c:       89 45 f0                mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp) // move this value into a new local variable, possible something like y = array[2];
804994f:       eb 08                   jmp    8049959 <level_3+0x50> 
8049951:       83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp) // add 1 to x so x = 1
8049955:       83 45 f0 04             addl   $0x4,-0x10(%ebp) // add the constant 4 to y so y += 4; 
8049959:       8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%ebp),%eax // move array[1] into the register
804995c:       39 45 f0                cmp    %eax,-0x10(%ebp) // compare array[1] to y. 
804995f:       7c f0                   jl     8049951 <level_3+0x48> // jump if it array[1] is less than y 



8049961:       83 7d f4 03             cmpl   $0x3,-0xc(%ebp) // compare this number 3 into the local variable x
8049965:       74 05                   je     804996c <level_3+0x63> // jump if they are equal to one another
8049967:       e8 e6 f9 ff ff          call   8049352 <call_function> // if it is not meeting these conditions, call function
804996c:       c7 45 f4 8c 00 00 00    movl   $0x8c,-0xc(%ebp) // move the constant 140 into the local variable x
8049973:       8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%ebp),%eax // move array[1] into the register
8049976:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax // test this value against itself
8049978:       75 05                   jne    804997f <level_3+0x76> // if it is not equal, jump
804997a:       e8 d3 f9 ff ff          call   8049352 <call_function> // if it is not meeting these conditions, call function
804997f:       c7 45 ec 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x8,-0x14(%ebp) // move the number 8 into the local variable z
8049986:       eb 30                   jmp    80499b8 <level_3+0xaf> // jump down and leave the function
8049988:       8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax // move arr[1] into the register
804998b:       83 e8 08                sub    $0x8,%eax // subtract 8 from arr[1]
804998e:       89 45 e8                mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp) // make this is the new arr[1] value


8049991:       83 7d f4 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp) // compare this number 0 to the local variable x
8049995:       75 17                   jne    80499ae <level_3+0xa5> // if it is not equal, then jump down to the subtraction (subl below)
8049997:       8b 45 e0                mov    -0x20(%ebp),%eax // move arr[0] into the register
804999a:       c1 f8 02                sar    $0x2,%eax // multiply by 4 (shifting it by 2 ^ 2)


804999d:       3b 45 ec                cmp    -0x14(%ebp),%eax // now move the variable z into the register
80499a0:       74 05                   je     80499a7 <level_3+0x9e> // if it is equal, then jump down
80499a2:       e8 ab f9 ff ff          call   8049352 <call_function> // if these conditions are not met, call_function
80499a7:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax // move the constant 0 into the register 
80499ac:       eb 1a                   jmp    80499c8 <level_3+0xbf> // jump down and leave the function
80499ae:       83 6d f4 07             subl   $0x7,-0xc(%ebp) // from x subtract 7
80499b2:       8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%ebp),%eax // move array[1] into the register
80499b5:       01 45 ec                add    %eax,-0x14(%ebp) // now add this to the variable z. so z += array[1];


80499b8:       83 7d ec 07             cmpl   $0x7,-0x14(%ebp) // compare the number 7 and the variable z
80499bc:       7f ca                   jg     8049988 <level_3+0x7f> // if it greater, then jump down
80499be:       e8 8f f9 ff ff          call   8049352 <call_function> // if these conditions are not met, call_function
80499c3:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax // move the constant 0 into the register
80499c8:       c9                      leave // leave the function
80499c9:       c3                      ret // return the value
```

My understanding:

- There is a parameter (a pointer which is here interpreted in my comments as an array) passed into a local variable int array[]. Then there are a series of comparisons between that and a few different constants along the way.
- I think that this is a while loop which is continually checking against some incremented condition as it goes around. I'm just not sure how to come up with what this condition is?

Assuming that the comments above are correct, how would I generate the right pseudocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the comments are correct you need to figure out which instructions are the machine doing it's business (lines `8049914` to `804993b`, for example, are just loading the args for `sscanf`; in C, it translates into

```
int *array[3];
int return_value = sscanf(param1, "%d %d %d", array[0], array[1], array[2]); 
if(return_value == 3): // If there were 3 integers... see sscanf documentation
    ...
```

You can figure out a lot with a couple of clues. For example, we now know the function prototype looks roughly like this:

```
level_3(char* param1 ...);
```

because we know the prototype for `sscanf`:

```
int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);
```

Also, remember the rule that the `%eax` register holds the return values for the called function, in this case `sscanf`, so the comparison is basically a check whether or not `param1` has 3 integers in it. Also, moving to some offset of `%esp` is setting up args for the function-to-be-called;  `-%ebp` is for locals variables, `+%ebp` is for the function's own parameters.

---

This is an example of the kind of reasoning to use when decoding assembly. You know what the stack looks like, roughly:

```
 ________
|params...                                               //<--- ebp
|...
|saved caller instruction pointer (%eip) // These might be mixed up
|saved caller return location on stack (%ebp)
|locals...
|...                                           
|space that could be used for a called functions's args  //<--- esp
```

The key to decoding assembly is to figure out how `mov`, `lea`, and the like translates into C; the pseudocode won't muck around with registers, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to understand assembly by disassemble existing program written in c.

As for gcc, make sure build your program with "-g" option which will add debug information to your program.

Then, just run "objdump -S [program]" which generate the assembly with mix of C source code, by this way, you can have a much better understanding by read assembly code only.